# How to get subtotal time stats for subexpressions in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to improve time performance (measured by `:set +s`) of my `main` and need to identify some bottlenecks. `main` invokes many functions that invoke `foo`. Is there a simple way to get GHCi to report the total time spent on multiple subcalls of `foo` only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For measuring performance, GHCi is not a good choice, since it often runs interpreted code, and does not optimize the code as GHC (the compiler) does. It is much better to *compile* the code with GHC, turning on optimizations `-O`.

When compiling, you can also turn on the [*profiler*](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/profiling.html) with `-prof -fprof-auto`. Doing so, running `yourProgram +RTS -p` will produce a report with all the costs for individual bindings (e.g. functions), helping you to identify the bottlenecks. You should be able, in this way, to obtain some report like this:

```
COST CENTRE MODULE                  no.     entries  %time %alloc   %time %alloc

MAIN        MAIN                    102           0    0.0    0.0   100.0  100.0
 CAF        GHC.IO.Handle.FD        128           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF        GHC.IO.Encoding.Iconv   120           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF        GHC.Conc.Signal         110           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF        Main                    108           0    0.0    0.0   100.0  100.0
  main      Main                    204           1    0.0    0.0   100.0  100.0
   main.g   Main                    207           1    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.1
    fib     Main                    208        1973    0.0    0.1     0.0    0.1
   main.f   Main                    205           1    0.0    0.0   100.0   99.9
    fib     Main                    206     2692537  100.0   99.9   100.0   99.9
```

You could also consider using the [`criterion`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/criterion-1.4.0.0/docs/Criterion.html) library to perform benchmarks. This is quite useful when trying to compare different implementations for the same function.